Creating own CSS grid, 'offset' class is messing with width
I'm trying to create my own CSS grid, with offset classes.
The problem is, when I apply the offset class to the column, it messes up the width of it and the column goes really narrow. Without the offset class the width works perfectly.


/* grid system */

.container {
  background: #999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  max-width: 1680px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.col {
  outline: 2px white dashed;
  padding: 15px;
}


/* cols */

.col-8 {
  grid-column: span 8;
}


/* col offsets */

.col-offset-1 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
<div class="container">
  <main class="row">
    <div class="col-8 col-offset-1">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum quibusdam perspiciatis, magnam autem velit totam quae consectetur tempora qui ipsum odit sed voluptatem quaerat error quos iusto aliquid nesciunt tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>



I've also realised that, if I specify a start column to the CSS, then it works properly in this instance. But I can't set that to every column class as it will mess up my layout:


/* grid system */

.container {
  background: #999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  max-width: 1680px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.col {
  outline: 2px white dashed;
  padding: 15px;
}


/* cols */

.col-8 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 8;
}


/* col offsets */

.col-offset-1 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
<div class="container">
  <main class="row">
    <div class="col-8 col-offset-1">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum quibusdam perspiciatis, magnam autem velit totam quae consectetur tempora qui ipsum odit sed voluptatem quaerat error quos iusto aliquid nesciunt tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>




Use grid-column: auto / span x as the default and then apply the grid-column-start: x which then overrides the auto. Otherwise the grid-column-start kinda "forgets" the
previously applied span 8

@Paulie_D Wow I cant believe it was that simple! Thanks... I tried something similar before but with '1' instead of 'auto', but I also forgot to add the '/' originally

One approach is as follows, which uses a custom CSS property to pass the relevant offset to the .col-8 content you're trying to place:


/* grid system */

.container {
  background: #999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  max-width: 1680px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.col {
  outline: 2px white dashed;
  padding: 15px;
}

/* cols */

.col-8 {
  /* here we're using the CSS calc() function to determine the
     column-grid-line at the start of the grid-column-track into
     which the content should be placed; this takes the form of
     1 + <offset>, as the starting edge of the grid is number 1.
     Into this calculation we pass in the --offset custom
     property or, if that property isn't defined, the default of
     0: */
  grid-column: calc(1 + var(--offset, 0)) / span 8;
}

/* col offsets */

.col-offset-1 {
  /* here we define the --offset property with the appropriate
     value: */
  --offset: 1;
}
<div class="container">
  <main class="row">
    <div class="col-8 col-offset-1">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum quibusdam perspiciatis, magnam autem velit totam quae consectetur tempora qui ipsum odit sed voluptatem quaerat error quos iusto aliquid nesciunt tenetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>



JS Fiddle demo.
References:

background.
display.
grid-column.
grid-template-columns.
margin.
max-width.
outline.
padding.
width.

